# tablesorter update widgetOptions for columnSelector

Tags: widget, config, tablesorter

i want to search column by name [image]

i tried to do this manually by

```
                table[0].config.widgetOptions.columnSelector_columns = {
                    2: true,
                    3: false
                };
```

and call table.trigger('update'); or 
table.trigger('applyWidgets'); or table.trigger('refreshColumnSelector');
but nothing working 
also tried refresh Widgets but its not working too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

* Please note * this widget & code only work on my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/).

You could target all (or both in this case) tables, then use the [jQuery `.each()` method](http://api.jquery.com/each/) like this:

```
$(".tablesorter")
    .each(function(i, table){
        var $table = $(table);
        $table.tablesorter({
            // ...
            widgetOptions: {
                // ...
                columnSelector_container : $('#columnSelector' + ( i + 1 )),
                // ...
            }
        })
        .bind('filterEnd', function(e, filter){
            // the current number of filtered rows is contained in config.filteredRows
            $table.prev('div').find('.filterCount').text( table.config.filteredRows );
        });
    });
```

and as for the css, you can group them together:

```
#colSelect1:checked + label, #colSelect2:checked + label {
    background: #5797d7;
    border-color: #555;
}
#colSelect1:checked ~ #columnSelector1, #colSelect2:checked ~ #columnSelector2 {
    display: block;
}
```